# Loop not showing first post

Tags: posts, loop

I've set up the following loop on a page, but it is missing out the first post. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
<div class="gallery">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
        <div class="view-item">
          <span>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p>View project</p>
          </span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
  <?php bones_page_navi(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK to me. There is nothing wrong with this part of your code.

Maybe some earlier part is doing something strange with your `$wp_query` variable.

You can try to add `rewind_posts()` before your loop - it should help. Just place `rewind_posts();`  just before `if (have_posts())...`.

Comment: Added `rewind_posts()` where you suggested and this worked. Wonder what was causing this!

Comment: Search for `the_post` function calls placed before this loop.